# Optimise compare and match method using scripting.dictionary in VBA

Tags: array, vba, excel, hash-map

In my previous post I was looking for a better solution to write a single column of a 2D array into a worksheet besides looping between code and worksheet and finally managed to achieve that.

On deploying my code, I found that the double loop to compare two arrays was inefficient when it came to comparing arrays of 5,000 or more and so I turned to the scripting.dictionary, for which I found the easiest instructions to follow [here](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html).

Here is an example that I have tested with arrays of 80,000 rows, returning results in seconds, but I am wondering if there might be some code I could cut or write better:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Sub arrayMatch()

    Dim firstArray As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        firstArray = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    End With

    Dim secondArray As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
        secondArray = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    End With

    Dim i As Long
    Dim dictKeyForLookup As String
    Dim dictValueToReturn As String

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    For i = LBound(firstArray, 1) To UBound(firstArray, 1)
        dictKeyForLookup = firstArray(i, 4)
        dictValueToReturn = firstArray(i, 3)
        If Not dict.Exists(dictKeyForLookup) Then
            dict.Add Key:=dictKeyForLookup, Item:=dictValueToReturn
        End If
    Next i

    Dim arrayToPaste As Variant
    ReDim arrayToPaste(UBound(secondArray, 1), 1)
    For i = LBound(secondArray, 1) To UBound(secondArray, 1)
        If dict.Exists(secondArray(i, 1)) Then
            arrayToPaste(i, 1) = dict.Item(secondArray(i, 1))
        End If
    Next i

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(UBound(secondArray, 1), 4)).Value = arrayToPaste
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This implementation actually looks really solid. A couple stylistic and micro-performance issues I would personally address:

**Array base:** I'd remove `Option Base 1` and explicitly declare your array dimensions. The problem with using `Option Base 1` is that it is a module level option, and it "taints" all of the code in the module with a non-default setting.  I consider it similar to using `#define foo bar` in C - it alters the *semantics* of your code. There's not even really a reason to use it in this case because you are always using the `LBound` to initialize your loop counters anyway. Changing this line...

> ```
> ReDim arrayToPaste(UBound(secondArray, 1), 1)
> ```

...to...

```
ReDim arrayToPaste(1 To UBound(secondArray, 1), 1 To 1)
```

...makes it *immediately* obvious that the array is 1 based without having to scroll to the top of the module or remember that the base is non-default.

**Variable naming:** `firstArray` and `secondArray` are about as meaningful as `a1` and `a2`. Something like `workingArray` and `comparisonArray` would make it a little more obvious what your code is dealing with.

**Worksheet references:** You are currently using magic numbers to locate the worksheets that you're operating on, and the indexes are based on the ordinal of where the sheet is in the collection.  If this is intended to operate on two fixed worksheets, use their class names instead.  This has two benefits: first, you aren't using 2 procedure calls (`Worksheets` and the implicit `Items`) to get a reference that you *already know and have access to* .  Second, your `Sub` won't break the first time you add a new worksheet. For example, use `With Sheet1` (or whatever it is) instead of `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`.

**Binding:**  There is no reason to late bind to the scripting runtime.  The interface hasn't changed in this century, and is unlikely to. This is a pretty good performance hit in exchange for absolutely zero upside. Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime and declare it explicitly:

```
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

**Use With appropriately:** You're doing this for your worksheets, but it doesn't actually ***do*** anything for you:

> ```
> With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
>     firstArray = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
> End With
> ```

You use it exactly once inside the block, so this is exactly the same thing as:

```
firstArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
'...or even better (see above)...
firstArray = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

What `With` does is hold an object reference to avoid having to dereference it multiple times.  If you only *use it* once, it's reduced to 2 extra lines of code and 1 extra indentation level.

That said, the place where it ***is*** appropriate is with your `Dictionary`, and it ***isn't*** used there. This is much better:

```
With New Scripting.Dictionary   'You don't even need the variable.
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    For i = LBound(firstArray, 1) To UBound(firstArray, 1)
        dictKeyForLookup = firstArray(i, 4)
        dictValueToReturn = firstArray(i, 3)
        If Not .Exists(dictKeyForLookup) Then
            .Add Key:=dictKeyForLookup, Item:=dictValueToReturn
        End If
    Next i

    Dim arrayToPaste As Variant
    ReDim arrayToPaste(1 To UBound(secondArray, 1), 1 To 1)
    For i = LBound(secondArray, 1) To UBound(secondArray, 1)
        If .Exists(secondArray(i, 1)) Then
            arrayToPaste(i, 1) = .Item(secondArray(i, 1))
        End If
    Next i
End With    'Dictionary goes out of scope here.
```

**Named arguments:** There is no reason to use them here:

```
dict.Add Key:=dictKeyForLookup, Item:=dictValueToReturn
```

If you are early bound, the name information is available via both Intellisense and the object browser.  If you are late bound, it actually adds more overhead for the runtime to resolve them. Just use the ordinal argument positions:

```
dict.Add dictKeyForLookup, dictValueToReturn
```

They're also a potential bug source because they are resolved at runtime for late bound objects (which is the same reason you take a performance hit).  That means that if you have a typo in the name (i.e. `Keey:=foo`), it won't be caught by the compiler.  It is also dependant on how the typelib is defined for the class.  For example it's possible for some *late bound* objects to introduce errors by specifying the same variable name multiple times.  Excel seems to be prone to this type of error:

```
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Sum(Arg1:=1, Arg1:=42) 'Prints 1
```

Comment: Well that was fast! "They're a potential bug source... but you're probably not interested" - the reader isn't only the OP! Feel free to expand on that =)

Comment: `Worksheets(1)` reference should be a variable, it's re-referenced at the end of the procedure ...but then again, using the existing global-scope objects would make that moot :-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Re named arguments, good point - I let my hunger get the better of me there (edited). Re `Worksheets(1)`, I actually typed that before I realized using the globals would moot it.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for expanding @Comintern, is mistyping named ranges the only potential bug source there? I will take your advice on board and do a rewrite, I think we may have just stumbled on my final version here :-)

Comment: Ah I see the other bug potential, I thought that VBA would always take the last variable name setting?

Comment: @IainSaunders - I had thought it would always be a compiler error, but it seems like the runtime and compiler are subtly broken in how it handles some of them.