# Comparing and pasting ranges of spreadsheet cells

Tags: array, vba, excel

I have a moderate size sub-procedure where I am calling multiple functions to feed values into other functions. I feel there may be a better or more concise way to present and run this module, but have refactored the code as far as I can see.

```
Public Sub CompareArrays()

    Dim matchCell As Range
    Set matchCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("A1")
    Dim matchArray As Variant
    matchArray = RangeToLastRow(matchCell)

    Dim compareCell As Range
    Set compareCell = matchCell.Parent.Range("B1")
    Dim compareArray As Variant
    compareArray = RangeToLastRow(compareCell)

    Dim arrayToPaste As Variant
    arrayToPaste = MatchArrays(matchArray, compareArray)

    RangeToLastRow(matchCell.Parent.Range("C1")) = arrayToPaste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution comes from [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142766/117814) where specifically the answer suggests a function to make an array. That seemed odd to me because it is a very simple matter to define an array from a range, but then the below occurred to me.

```
Dim myArray As Variant
myArray = Range("A1:A10")
Dim arrayToPaste As Variant
arrayToPaste = MatchArrays(myArray, etc)
```

Could also be written as:

```
Dim arrayToPaste As Variant
arrayToPaste = MatchArrays(MakeArray("A1:A10"), etc)
```

Simply by passing the function as an argument I have removed two additional lines of code and it is still clear what is happening.

Going a step further, we can also integrate the RangeToLastRow function in the OP and finish off the Sub.

```
Public Sub CompareArrays()

    Dim arrayToPaste As Variant
    arrayToPaste = MatchArrays( _
        MakeArray(RangeToLastRow(ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("A1")), _
        MakeArray(RangeToLastRow(ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("B1"))

    RangeToLastRow(ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("C1")) = arrayToPaste

End Sub
```

As long as we use descriptive function names, it should still be clear what we are doing to the inputs without having to Dim a whole lot of extra variables.

Edit:

Another method is to move the functions out of the arguments and into the function that is called, for example:

```
Public Sub CompareArrays()

    Dim arrayToPaste As Variant
    arrayToPaste = MatchArrays( _
        RangeToLastRow(ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("A1"), _
        RangeToLastRow(ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("B1"))

    RangeToLastRow(ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("C1")) = arrayToPaste

End Sub

Sub MatchArrays(ByRef MatchRange As Range, ByRef CompareRange As Range)

    matchArray = MakeArray(MatchRange)
    compareArray = MakeArray(CompareRange)

   '*do stuff '

End Sub
```

Comment: Careful with inlining: if an error occurs in `RangeToLastRow` it will be harder to debug an instruction with 7 statements than one instruction that does fewer things. IMO an instruction that spans 3 lines is a bit too much. The number of lines of code isn't a measure of anything other than... the number of lines of code.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to split operations up into atomic parts *even when they could be put in one function call*.  At the end of the day, once you've abstracted away some operations into a method, you're never going to care if it's overly verbose, but you're going to be *really* thankful when something breaks and you need to debug it.